# Prove that $f(x)=x^4$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I understand that we want $\varepsilon$ so that $|x^2+y^2||x+y||x-y|<\varepsilon$, and for $|x+y||x-y|<\varepsilon$ I can choose $\delta$ so that $\delta(2|y|+\delta)<\varepsilon$, but I don't know what to do with the $|x^2+y^2|$ part.

Comment: you know $k(x)=x$ is continous, and if $h$ and $S$ be two continous function then$h.S$ is continous, too. thus $f(x)=x^4$ is continous

Comment: But is it rigorous enough to say that since $f(x)=x^4=x*x*x*x$ and each $f(x)=x$ is continuous, then the product of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: yes, it is, $a(x)=f(x).f(x)=x^2$ is continous, $f(x)=a(x).a(x)=x^4$ is continous, even you can show by induction $m(x)=x^n$ is continous.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is not going to be uniform. You want to show continuity at a fixed $y$, say. You will want $|x-y|<\delta$. Then $|x|<|y|+\delta$, so 
$$\tag{1}
|x^4-y^4|=|x^2+y^2|\,|x+y|\,|x-y|<(|y|+\delta)^2+y^2)\,(2|y|+\delta)\,|x-y|.
$$
To make this less that $\varepsilon$, you choose $\delta$ so that
$$
|x-y|<\frac\varepsilon{(|y|+\delta)^2+y^2)\,(2|y|+\delta)}.
$$
It is still not that obvious how to choose $\delta$. But if you first force $\delta<1$, say, then $(1)$ becomes 
$$
|x^4-y^4|=|x^2+y^2|\,|x+y|\,|x-y|<(|y|+\delta)^2+y^2)\,(2|y|+\delta)\,|x-y|
<((|y|+1)^2+y^2)(2|y|+1)\,|x-y|,
$$
and now you can choose 
$$
\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon{(|y|+1)^2+y^2)\,(2|y|+1)}\right\}.
$$

Comment: Is picking $\delta<1$ arbitrary? Just to clear up the inequality?

Comment: Yes, the point is to make it less than a fixed number so you can bound it out of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=0$, then $|x^4-y^4|=x^4< \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|=|x|<\epsilon^{1/4}$.  So, take $\delta=\epsilon^{1/4}$.

If $y\ne 0$, then take $|x-y|<y/2$ so that $y/2<x<3y/2$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
|x^4-y^4|&=|x-y|(x+y)(x^2+y^2)\\\\
&<|x-y|\left(\frac52 y\right)\left(\frac{13}{4}y^2\right)\\\\
&=|x-y|\frac{65}{8}y^3\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-y|<\frac{8}{65y^3}\epsilon$.

So, let $\delta =\min\left(\frac{y}{2},\frac{8}{65y^3}\epsilon\right)$.  Then, for all $\epsilon>0$, $|x^4-y^4|<\epsilon$ for any $x>0$,

Comment: Can you explain a bit the intuition behind making $\delta<\frac{y}{2}$?

Comment: Sure. The choice was not unique.  We had already addressed the case for which $y=0$.  Then, when $y\ne 0$, as long as $|x-y|<y/2$, then we have $x>y/2>0$ also; so, we need not worry about having $x$ outside the interval $[0,\infty)$.  Note that we could have take $\delta <y/4$ or $2y/19$ or any other choice less than $y$ itself.  The choice of $1/2$ was, therefore, arbitrary.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark